# Required field in Eureka form

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I want to do required field if  row  percentageField  or valueField isn't nil.

`KalkulatinTag` is enum:

```
enum KalkulationTag: Int {
    case skonto = 11
    case tage= 22
}
```

Hese is code in KalculationCell ViewController:

```
if (self.tag == KalkulationTag.skonto.rawValue) {
    if ((percentageField.text != nil) || (valueField.text != nil)) {
        if (self.tag == KalkulationTag.skonto.rawValue){
            //here should be required field of eureka
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the code that calls eureka forms: KalkulationRow is Costum row and IntRow is Eureka row. I want IntRow() value to be required.

```
form +++ Section("SKONTO")
    <<< IntRow() {
            $0.title = "Tage:"
            $0.cell.tag = KalkulationTag.tage.rawValue
        }
    <<< KalkulationRow { row in
            row.cell.tag = KalkulationTag.skonto.rawValue
        }
```

Project is here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [validation](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#validations) docs at Eureka, required row can be created by adding `RuleRequired` rule to the row. Also, there is function that allows you to remove any rule you want.

So, the strategy should be like this:

1) On initial row setup check the `percentageField` and `valueField` values. If any of those equal to nil or empty - add `RuleRequired` to the row.

2) Next step you should manage [`onChanged`](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#callbacks-list) closure. Again, for `percentageField` and `valueField` check in `onChanged` closure, that rows has a value not a nil or empty. If row has values - remove required rule, if has - add.